# Azure DevOps: Deny viewing "Task Groups" to Readers/Project Valid Users

Tags: security, azure-devops

**I just realized any user can see `Task Groups`.** And also inside Task Groups.
Even though I disabled "view build and release pipelines".

And even though in the Security Settings, `Readers` is not even listed in the permissions.

[image]

Any advice how I can prevent this?
I tried adding Readers with a deny all setting... but obviously there isn't even a permission for "viewing". So your best advice is to not do any secret magic in your task groups? ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Azure DevOps: Deny viewing “Task Groups” to Readers/Project Valid Users

Sorry for any inconvenience.

This behavior is **by designed**. There is no way to fix it at present, and current advice is not to include secret magic in your task groups.

To build a better Azure DevOps, I submit your request for this feature on our UserVoice site (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21 ), which is our main forum for product suggestions:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/820090/add-enabledisable-view-task-group-permission-for-t.html

You could vote and add your comments for this feedback. When there are enough communities vote and add comments for this feedback, the product team member will take this feedback seriously.

Hope this helps.